# v-close-popup not working when toggleFullscreen is true

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to close a popup by click of a button, but when we show the popup in full screen i.e toggleFullscreen is true we are not able to close the popup.

Button to close the popup:
`<q-btn flat label="X" v-close-popup />`

Full screen toggle:

```
<q-btn
     @click="props.toggleFullscreen"
></q-btn>
```

I wanted to close the pop when toggleFullscreen is true.

Comment: Without looking into the minimal reproducible example. It will be difficult to tell the exact issue which you are facing.